# Why I paste the string into the bash command line in the putty window I always get a wave mark at the head of the string?

Tags: putty

I use the Windows as my main `os`, and the putty link to a `Ubuntu`. When I copy a string in Windows and paste into the putty bash command line I always get a `wave mark` at the head of the string. Why's that? 
But if I paste the same string when I enter `vim` in the putty, the string shows fine without the `wave mark`. How to fix it?

[This is what is shown on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxJFd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason when I use the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>. The text pasted in the putty will get a `~` at the head of the string.

But if you use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> the `~` will not show out.

`shift + insert` seems to be a special mark in the putty. If you make you clipboard empty just press `shift + ins` in the putty window you will get only `~`.
[1221105902.png](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/1221105902.png)

But sometimes `Ctrl + v` will trigger other things (like the **block-wise visual** in vim). So you can use AHK in windows.
Now I use the `AHK` to imitate the keystroke `shift + insert`

And the code should be like this:

```
^v::
{
send, +{ins}
return
}
```

hope this will be useful to you~